# How do I store files in googleappengine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob, google-cloud-datastore

Just wondering how to store files in the google app engine datastore.
There are lots of examples on the internet, but they are using blobstore

I have tried importing db.BlobProperty, but when i put() the data
it shows up as a `<Blob>` i think. It appears like there is no data
Similar to None for a string

Are there any examples of using the Datastore to store files
Or can anyone point me in the right direction
I am new to programming, so not to complex, but I have a good
hang of Python, just not an expert yet.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you want to store files in the datastore? That's not really what it's for - you should have taken the hint that most examples use blobstore. That's what you should do, too.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is completely correct here. Think of the datastore as a  database that holds textual entries.

Answer (score 0):

Datastore has a limit on the size of objects stored there, thats why all examples and documentation say to use the blobstore or cloud storage. Do that.